# How to change a slot from character to numeric in a S4 object

Tags: r, type-conversion, r-s4

I recently started working with S4 and as inexperienced I have faced (probably very basic) problem of this nature. I opened an inherited SQLite file in RStudio and most of the variables in the @Data slot are now characters:

```
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 6 
extent      : -6.39025, -6.19989, 57.41705, 58.24892  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 10
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  x_s            y_s           x_f            y_f           code  bike  area_of_us area_of_wo code_1   len
  <chr>          <chr>         <chr>          <chr>         <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>       <int> <int>
1 -6.38920256712 58.2211623275 -6.37986139687 58.2146668412 10828 4     S02001693  S02001694   10828  1450
2 -6.37986139687 58.2146668412 -6.38920256712 58.2211623275 10833 15    S02001694  S02001693   10833  1318
3 -6.33650176593 58.2476612701 -6.37986139687 58.2146668412 10827 1     S02001692  S02001694   10827  7095
4 -6.33650176593 58.2476612701 -6.38920256712 58.2211623275 10831 2     S02001692  S02001693   10831  6154
5 -6.33650176593 58.2476612701 -6.23520212958 58.2170837741 10836 1     S02001692  S02001695   10836 16725
6 -6.33489444379 57.469233209  -6.19991100961 57.4179104112 12570 3     S02002010  S02002009   12570 11735
```

I need to convert the "bike" variable into numeric. Does anyone know how I can do this? Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers,
Irena

Comment: Could you post what you have tried already, and what error messages you got? (For instance, what happens when you try `x$bike <- as.numeric(x$bike)` (assuming your data frame is called `x`)

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I just finished a modelling process with exactly the same approach: `var_bicycle_Scotland@data$bike <- as.numeric(var_bicycle_Scotland@data$bike)` In this case, my dataframe is called var_bicycle_Scotland. But what happens when I save the file to a GeoJSON format and open it back in QGIS, all the routes appear segmented. Previously I also tried with {dplyr} `mutate`  and  `transmute`. Same happened at the end. I don't understand why my routes which if opened directly from the original file look fine, but once I convert the bike count into numeric, they become segmented

Comment: after converting the bike variable into a numeric, I run the following to aggregate the flows `Scottish_flows_aggregated <- stplanr::overline(var_bicycle_Scotland, attrib = "bike", fun = sum, na.zero = FALSE, buff_dist = 0)`
`writeOGR(Scottish_flows_aggregated, dsn = "Scottish_flows_aggregated_2.0.GeoJSON", layer = "bike", driver = "GeoJSON")`

Comment: I think I have figured out why my routes get segmented, it is exactly the result of the `stplnr::overline` function. It summarizes the number of bikes per segment along the route. Thanks @JDL for your suggestion, that did the trick indeed for the conversion of the 'bike' variable from `chr` to `num`.